# C Sockets Blocking for Unknown Reason

Tags: c, macos, sockets, tcp, blocking

I am trying to write a basic TCP echo server in C on macOS Catalina. I'm following my environment's manpages and these webpages: [TCP Server-Client implementation in C - GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tcp-server-client-implementation-in-c/) and [Server and client example with C sockets on Linux - BinaryTides](https://www.binarytides.com/server-client-example-c-sockets-linux/).

For some reason my client (I believe) is blocking on it's first call to `recv`. I'm new to socket programming, so I do not know why this could be. Why isn't my client printing out the response it should be getting from the server?

## server.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sysexits.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <arpa/inet.h>

#include <sys/socket.h>

#define CLOSE(fildes) if (close(fildes) == -1) {            \
    perror("call to `close` failed");               \
    exit(EX_OSERR);                         \
}

#define MAXCONNS 4
#define MSGLEN 1023

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    long port;
    int passive_fildes, active_fildes;
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    ssize_t length;
    char message[MSGLEN];

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s <port>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EX_USAGE);
    }
    if ((port = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10)) > UINT16_MAX || port < 1024) {
        fputs("invalid port argument\n", stderr);
        exit(EX_USAGE);
    }
    if ((passive_fildes = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
        perror("failed to create socket");
        exit(EX_OSERR);
    }
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    address.sin_port = htons(port);
    if (bind(passive_fildes, (struct sockaddr *)&address,
        sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) == -1) {
        perror("failed to bind socket");
        CLOSE(passive_fildes);
        exit(EX_OSERR);
    }
    if (listen(passive_fildes, MAXCONNS) == -1) {
        perror("failed to listen for connections");
        CLOSE(passive_fildes);
        exit(EX_OSERR);
    }
    /* Accept connections indefinitely. */
    for (;;) {
        if ((active_fildes = accept(passive_fildes, NULL, NULL)) ==
            -1) {
            perror("failed to accept connection");
            /* Should we exit here? */
            continue;
        }
        /* Respond to requests until client disconnects. */
        while ((length = recv(active_fildes, message, MSGLEN, 0)) !=
            0) {
            if (length == -1) {
                perror("failed to receive request");
                continue;
            }
            if (message[length-1] != '\n') {
                fprintf(stderr, "request was over %d ", MSGLEN);
                fprintf(stderr, "characters in length\n");
                /* We break the client if we don't respond. */
                break;
            }
            if (send(active_fildes, message, (size_t)length, 0) ==
                -1) {
                perror("failed to send response");
                /* We break the client if we don't respond. */
                break;
            }
        }
        CLOSE(active_fildes);
    }
    CLOSE(passive_fildes);
    return 0;
}
```

## client.c

```
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sysexits.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <arpa/inet.h>

#include <sys/socket.h>

#define CLOSE(fildes) if (close(fildes) == -1) {            \
    perror("call to `close` failed");               \
    exit(EX_OSERR);                         \
}

#define MSGLEN 1023

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    long port;
    int fildes;
    char message[MSGLEN+1];
    ssize_t length;

    if (argc != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s <address> <port>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EX_USAGE);
    }
    if (inet_aton(argv[1], &address.sin_addr) == 0) {
        perror("invalid address argument\n");
        exit(EX_USAGE);
    }
    if ((port = strtol(argv[2], NULL, 10)) > UINT16_MAX || port < 1024) {
        fputs("invalid port argument\n", stderr);
        exit(EX_USAGE);
    }
    if ((fildes = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
        perror("failed to create socket");
        exit(EX_OSERR);
    }
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_port = htons(port);
    if (connect(fildes, (struct sockaddr *)&address,
        sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) == -1) {
        perror("failed to connect to server");
        CLOSE(fildes);
        exit(EX_NOHOST);
    }
    while (fgets(message, MSGLEN+1, stdin) != NULL) {
        /* Check whether the entire request was read. */
        if (message[strlen(message)-1] != '\n') {
            fprintf(stderr, "request was over %d ", MSGLEN);
            fprintf(stderr, "characters in length\n");
            /* Gobble the rest of the request. */
            while (fgetc(stdin) != '\n');
            continue;
        }
        if (send(fildes, message, strlen(message), 0) == -1) {
            perror("failed to send request");
            continue;
        }
        /* Don't clobber the EOS! */
        if ((length = recv(fildes, message, MSGLEN, 0)) == -1) {
            perror("failed to receive response");
            /* Not reading response is an error condition. */
            CLOSE(fildes);
            exit(EX_OSERR);
        }
        if (length == 0) {
            fputs("server unexpectedly closed connection", stderr);
            CLOSE(fildes);
            exit(EX_PROTOCOL);
        }
        /* Check whether the entire response was read. */
        if (message[length-1] != '\n') {
            fprintf(stderr, "response was over %d ", MSGLEN);
            fprintf(stderr, "characters in length\n");
            /* Gobble the rest of the response. */
            do if (recv(fildes, message, 1, 0) == -1) {
                perror("failed to gobble extra characters");
                /* This is an error condition. */
                CLOSE(fildes);
                exit(EX_OSERR);
            } while (message[0] != '\n');
            /* Can still print partial response. */
        }
        /* Validate the response with an EOS. */
        message[length] = '\0';
        if (fputs(message, stdout) == -1) {
            perror("failed to print response out");
            continue;
        }
    }
    if (!feof(stdin)) {
        perror("failed to read request in");
        CLOSE(fildes);
        exit(EX_OSERR);
    }
    CLOSE(fildes);
    return 0;
}
```

## Server Console

```
$ ./server 8080
entered main loop
accepted connection
received request: hello
sent response: hello
```

## Client Console

```
$ ./client 127.0.0.1 8080
connected to server
hello
```

After the client printed out the connection message, I entered "hello"; however, the client never output a response from the server. Note the debug print statement on line 73 in client.c is never executed. This shows that the `recv` call does not correctly complete. However, the debug print statement on line 87 in server.c is executed, which shows that the server completes its `send` call.

I tried very carefully to write correct C code, so if any of you have comments about safety or style, please give them!

Comment: You are ignoring the possibility that `recv()` returns zero.

Comment: @user207421 I think that would only happen in server closed the socket prior to sending any data.  Based on server output, there is no indication that this is happening.

Comment: @user207421, thanks for noting that possibility. I fixed my code to account for it, but that didn't fix my problem.

Comment: Can you provide a complete terminal transcript?

Comment: Wait a second, if I switch my port to from 8080 to 11111, it works! Why is that? Aren't all ports over 1023 a free for all?

Comment: Maybe it's another running server or firewall. My client can connect to port 8080 even when there's no server running.

Comment: What does `netstat -anp tcp | grep 8080` show?

Comment: The command didn't show anything. Also, my client successfully connected, but the peer reset the connection when the client tried to send a message.

Comment: Try to run the `netstat` while the client is connected.  By the way I tested port 8080 on my mac and it worked, so you must have some additional software installed that binds to this port.

Comment: Still didn't show anything. You know, I just realized that I enabled Apache about a week ago. Maybe that's it.

Comment: Try browsing to it... ?

Comment: Said server unexpectedly closed connection. Maybe Apache is reserving the port. I don't get it.

Comment: You are ignoring the possibility that `recv()` returned zero, which would indeed happen if the peer closed the connection before sending any data, which is a possibility that you cannot ignore. You can't write correct code without covering all the possibilities, and this is particularly true of networking code. If you are really trying to 'write correct C code', start here.